# Cypress - How to handle basic auth pop-up after click

Tags: javascript, authentication, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm working on the automation of a ticket sales page for soccer matches. The web is in pre-production and for this reason it asks me for a basic auth when accessing to the page.

That's why when accessing I do the following command:

`cy.visit('https://user:pass@tickets.demo.com/')`

But currently the client has added another basic auth that appears in the payment gateway after pressing the pay button with a simple click.

In the previous version of the project, he magically ignore the pop-up and kept going, but recently I migrate to the latest version of Cypress and now the project crashes when I reach that step with an Authentication error. How can I handle it?

Researching a bit I have seen the following code but it only works after a visit command, but I need after a click.

```
cy.visit('your url', {
 auth: {
  username: 'enter username',
  password: 'enter password,          
 },
})
```

Old Cypress: 9.5.1
New Cypress: 10.8.0
Node:  8.13.2